# AWS CLI Unknown options: --environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to create lambda function via awscli but getting error:

> Unknown options: --environment,

Steps performed:

```
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 

ESENDPOINT="search-iacapps-es-ggkr4trzo5ezjxqchkiva.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"

root@ip-172-31-21-120:/# aws lambda create-function --function-name es-cleanup-lambda --environment Variables={es_endpoint=$ESENDPOINT} --zip-file fileb://es-cleanup-lambda.zip --description "Elastichsearch Index Cleanup" --role arn:aws:iam::342234566657195:role/es-cleanup-lambda --handler es-cleanup.lambda_handler --runtime python2.7 --timeout 180
    usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
    To see help text, you can run:

      aws help
      aws <command> help
      aws <command> <subcommand> help

    **Unknown options: --environment**, Variables={es_endpoint=search-iacapps-es-ggkr4trzo5ezjxqchkiva.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com}

    cli --version
    Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Debian 4.2.1.102+dfsg2-7ubuntu4)
    Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
            TLS:           __thread
            SIGSEGV:       altstack
            Notifications: epoll
            Architecture:  amd64
            Disabled:      none
            Misc:          softdebug
            LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
            GC:            sgen
    pip --version
    pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Update did not help.

Comment: Just update your `aws-cli` using `pip install awscli --upgrade`.

Comment: What do you get when you run `aws --version`?

Comment: Thanks you very much guys . I did pip install awscli --upgrade and run command again via cli and it worked . I wounder why it was not working earlier when i tried multiple times to upgrade it . But issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading with 'pip install awscli --upgrade' you will need to restart the shell.